# How do I safely import MySQL data in a directory to a running MariaDB server?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, migration, import, mariadb

We're integrating another office into ours.  That includes some of their data.

I have a new installed MariaDB 5.5 server.  The data dir = /home/data/MariaDB.  I've done a new/fresh install into that directory:

```
ls -1 /home/data/MariaDB
    ibdata1
    ib_logfile0
    ib_logfile1
    multi-master.info
    mysql/
    mysql_upgrade_info
    performance_schema/
    test/
```

The server is up & running.

I inherited some data from a now-defunct MySQL server.  It's in:

```
ls -1 /home/data/MySQL-OLD
    auto.cnf
    ibdata1
    ib_logfile0
    ib_logfile1
    mysql/
    mysql_upgrade_info
    performance_schema/
    proj_DB_2136/
    proj_DB_4216/
    proj_DB_6217/
    test/
```

I want to move data for three DBs --  "proj_DB_2136/", "proj_DB_4216/", and "proj_DB_6217/" -- into my working MariaDB server.  Same names, same data, everything.

I just need to do this one time, so I can start working on the old data on my new server.

I'd like to do it the right way, without losing anything!

`mysqldump` makes sense for me, but only for working databases already IN the running server.

What's the correct way to get this data safely brought over?

Comment: Are the tables `MyISAM` or `InnoDB` or a mix of both?

Comment: The inherited data has a mix of both.  Once I get the data onto my new server, I'll convert to InnoDB.

Comment: I need help with this same thing -sigh-